# Нужна помощь в составлении метода поиска одинаковых значений в соседних ячейках двумерного массива

Tags: java

Есть массив

```
int[][] inColor = new int[6][6];
```

нужно создать метод который будет принимать координаты элемента (`i` и `j` например) и искать в соседних (верхнем, нижнем, правом, левом ) одинаковые значения что и в полученном.

Comment: И в чем проблема-то? Проверяйте соседние ячейки.

Comment: Проблема в том что не у всех есть соседние с каждой стороны,а отдельное условие для каждой ячейки писать не хочется.

Comment: @Максим ну так и проверьте указанная ячейка находится на одном из краев или нет. если да - исключаете эту сторону из проверки.

Comment: Если б я знал как это сделать,сюда бы не пришел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код неоптимизирован (нет проверки на исключения, на предмет ввода корректных данных и многое другое). Кто-то может предложит вариант лучше.

Вот что примерно может получится:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{



    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int SIZE = 6;
        final Random random = new Random();
        ArrayList nums = new ArrayList();

        int[][] arr = new int[SIZE][SIZE];

        // Считываем данные и присваиваем значения переменным
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int x = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int y = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        /* Раскоментировать ЭТО и закоментировать СЧИТЫВАНИЕ данных из буфера для тестирования
        // на статических входных данных
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        */

        /* Формируем исходный массив */
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
                arr[i][j] = random.nextInt(3) + 1; // Чтоб чаще попадались совпадения.. можно увеличить рандом
            }
        }

        /* Отображение сформированного массива */
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }


        int cellNum = x * SIZE + y;
        /* Складываем ближайшие номера массива, подходящие условию в лист */
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE * SIZE; ++i) {
            if (cellNum == i) {
                if (cellNum >= 0) {
                    if (cellNum - SIZE >= 0) {
                        nums.add(cellNum - SIZE);
                    }

                    if (cellNum % SIZE != 0) {
                        nums.add(cellNum - 1);
                    }

                    if ((cellNum + 1) % SIZE != 0) {
                        nums.add(cellNum + 1);
                    }

                    if (cellNum + SIZE < SIZE * SIZE) {
                        nums.add(cellNum + SIZE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* Выводим результаты в виде координат найденных ячеек (строка, стобец)  */
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            int _x = (int)nums.get(i) / SIZE;
            int _y = (int)nums.get(i) % SIZE;
            if (arr[_x][_y] == arr[x][y]) {
                System.out.print("(" + _x + ", " + _y + "); ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пощупать тут можно: https://ideone.com/98d7O4

А вообще для решения, порой, неплохо на листочке нарисовать данные и почеркать на черновике что и как. Визуальное отображение задачи - помогает увидеть некоторые аспекты, которые нельзя продумать сразу в голове.